# VS Code build task doesn't find include path

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, makefile

I have downloaded a C SDK, inside this SDK are Makfiles that I can use to build the included example applications. To get started with a more advanced development, I wanted to setup VS Code so that I can use it like an "IDE".
To get the build task running, I have created a bash-script that calls the function needed to build the examples. From the terminal this script runs as expected, but when I call it via the build task of VS Code, the compiler says "No such file or directory" for all includes from the include folder. How can I fix this?
(I have added the include path to c_cpp_properties, so IntelliSense already knows the included files)

Thanks for your help!

**Tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "../build.sh",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Task-Output**

```
> Executing task: ../build.sh <

make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: ../build.sh <

cc -g -I -o example.o -c example.c 
example.c:15:29: fatal error: error_code_user.h: No such file or directory
 #include "error_code_user.h"
                             ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'example.o' failed
make: *** [example.o] Error 1
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', '../build.sh'" failed to launch (exit code: 2).
```

**build.sh**

```
make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -m32 -msse -msse2 -D__X86__"
```

**Makefile (Main folder)**

```
CC ?= gcc
INC_PATH ?= $(realpath ../inc)
LIB_PATH ?= $(realpath ../lib)
LIBS ?= -Wl,-Bstatic -lexamples -Wl,-Bdynamic -pthread -lrt -lm -lzmq
EXTRA_CFLAGS =
CFLAGS += $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
export CFLAGS INC_PATH LIB_PATH LIBS

EXAMPLES := example example2 example3
SUBDIRS := libitsmsg example example2 example3

.PHONY: all $(EXAMPLES)

all: $(EXAMPLES)

example:
    make -C example

example2:
    make -C example2

itsmsg: 
    make -C libitsmsg

example3:
    make -C example3

clean:
    $(foreach d, $(SUBDIRS), make -C $(d) clean;)
```

**Makefile (example)**

```
CC ?= gcc
INC_PATH ?= $(realpath ../inc)
LIB_PATH ?= $(realpath ../lib)
LIBS ?= $(wildcard $(LIB_PATH)/*.a) -pthread -lrt -lm
LDFLAGS :=-g -L$(LIB_PATH)
CFLAGS +=-g -I$(INC_PATH)

EXAMPLES=example

.PHONY: all

all: $(EXAMPLES)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< 

example: example.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN/../../lib'

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o $(EXAMPLES)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got my answer!
It just depends of the perspective from where I call the build process. So my "problem" was, that there are relative paths in the Makefile. So when I call make from the wrong perspecitve, INC_PATH and LIB_PATH are wrong.
For now I fixed it by using absolute paths.